# setspace.sty not found

Tags: installing, setspace

I'm trying to do double-spacing using the `setspace` package, but I'm getting a `setspace.sty` not found error. My code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\doublespacing
body
\end{document}
```

Is this wrong? Is the `setspace` package out of date? Is it possible it is not installed on my system? I'm the Emacs LaTeX package (TeX Live I think it is called?)

Comment: The `setspace` package is usually part of a standard distribution.  What operating system are you using, and what TeX distribution?

Comment: You can check which packages are installed on your system, or at least install new ones using `tlmgr`. It will also take care of setting the path for installed package - typical to a problem of your nature.

Comment: If you are on some Linux system you might need to install more than just the basic TeX package. For example on Debian/Ubuntu `setspace` is contained in `texlive-latex-recommended`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my system (MacTeX 2011), the file `setspace.sty` is at `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/setspace/setspace.sty`. If the file `setspace.sty` is really missing from your TeX distribution, you can find a copy online at http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/setspace/setspace.sty. As others will no doubt also point out, it's usually best to run a package management program, such as `tlmgr` (TeXLive Manager), as doing so will automatically take care of updating all filename databases that TeX's programs rely on.